# How do I add information from one CSV file to another based off of matching values in Python?

Tags: python, excel, csv, join, merge

I am trying to combine data from multiple CSV files into one CSV file. I have several files that have similar information. I want to add the information that I don't have to a single CSV file by matching similar cell data and appending the missing information to that corresponding row.

This is an image of the CSV file I want to add information to:
[table I want to add to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0qhR.png)

This is an image of the CSV file I want to parse for information, and then add missing information to the joined CSV file: [table I want to take information from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afkNb.png)

This is what I want my CSV file to look like in the end: [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA03x.png)

I have simply copy and pasted here to demonstrate my goal, however I have a ton of data that I would like to add by checking it against my source table.

My strategy so far has been to use the CSV module and create a nested for loop that compares against the two rows. Right now my code only tries to see if there is a match between the two tables without trying to append anything. This is also proving difficult.

My output so far looks like this: [current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8Nuv.png)
(*note that in this image I was trying to add superintendent info, that is why the output is showing a name instead of the other information*)

My code is iterating over more than I wanted. I was hoping that it would just compare the dictionary values I had called to.

```
#Python 3.6.4    
import csv
import codecs

count = 0
original_csv = codecs.open("Texas School Districts.csv", 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
fieldnames1 = ['NCES LEA ID', 'State ID', 'District Name']
reader1 = csv.DictReader(original, fieldnames=fieldnames1)

additional_info = codecs.open("new_information.csv", 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
fieldnames2 = ['Name', 'District', 'Type', 'Description']
reader2 = csv.DictReader(additional_info, fieldnames=fieldnames2)
    
for row1 in reader1:
    for row2 in reader2:
        if row1['District Name'] == row2['Name']:
            print(row1['District Name'], ":", row2['Name'])
        else:
            pass
    count += 1  
    original.seek(count)
    append.seek(0)
```

What would you guys recommend I do to accomplish the task of merging new data to existing values? Am I on the right track or have I gone way off? Please let me know if you have any questions, or if I can provide any more information. I hope I made some sense.

Comment: I would seriously contemplate using a database like SQLITE or Postrgres and just dumping your data into them, and using SQL to manipulate the data.  It's easier, and more efficient.

Comment: `for row1 in reader1:
    for row2 in reader2:` this double loop won't work since the file will be consumed at first pass in the inner loop.

Comment: Are you using python3?

Comment: @DataHerder I am using Python 3.6.4, I will update my post to state this.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I had issues with the double loop at first because of this but by adding the .seek() methods that doesn't seem to be the problem anymore.

Comment: Then you don't need `codecs`, you can import just using `csv`.

Comment: okay but double loop are extremely unefficient. create a dictionary instead with contents of table 2 to avoid the loop

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yea it is crazy inefficient lol. Could you guide me through the dictionary method? I am rather new to this and would love to learn more.

Comment: I say either use a database, or use pandas and the merge capability to join your tables:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: @anishtain4 I switched to Pandas and used the merge method. This got me the desired results. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continue doing this in native python, and not pandas, or a real database, you *have* to make this code faster:

```
for row1 in reader1:
    for row2 in reader2:
        if row1['District Name'] == row2['Name']:
            print(row1['District Name'], ":", row2['Name'])
        # seek to avoid reader2 to be EOF ...
```

no need for the second loop if you build a lookup `set` beforehand:

```
existing_names = {row["Name"] for row in reader2}
```

now use a single loop, and no need to rewind files:

```
for row1 in reader1:
    if row1['District Name'] in existing_names: # set lookup is faaast
            print(row1['District Name'])
```

Now code runs in `O(n)` (average) vs `O(n**2)`

Comment: This looks much more efficient! I will definitely take a look at Pandas, but this looks like something that I can try.

Comment: @ Jean-François Fabre I switched to Pandas and used the merge method. That solved my problem and did so very quickly! Thank you for recommending it.